# Sitecore Identity Service in the Azure App Service is empty

Tags: azure, identity-server

On the `IdentityServer` I need to access the `Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml` file to update the values of `AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1` and  `PasswordRecoveryUrl` to be the new DNS for the CM instance.

This is easy to do on `XP0` locally. But when accessing the `IdentityServer` App Service in Azure the `wwwroot` is empty. What directory is the `Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml` file located and the rest of the `IdentityServer` .NET Core app?

Comment: No it isn't. Empty, that is. Ours sits in `/wwwroot/Config/production/Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml`. Are you sure you're looking in the App that ends with `si` and not the `si-hp` one?

Comment: I'm looking at the app service that ends with `si`. I've spun up a new `XP1` and have the same issue where the `si` is empty. There are errors during the execution of the script but told by Sitecore Support that they are related to the Machine Learning params being empty but told they're not required

Comment: Well, I would say they're wrong :P  there most definitely should be a file structure in the SI WebApp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the the `wwwroot` being empty for the `IdentityServer` was that the wrong web deploy package was used for the `IdentityServer` param in the `parameters.json`

```
"siMsDeployPackageUrl": {
      "value": "<url of your sitecore identity server deploy package>/Sitecore.IdentityServer.2.0.1-r00166.scwdp.zip"
    },
```

The web deploy package of the `IdentityServer` is a separate download from the rest of Sitecore Web Deploy Packages and can be found here - https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Identity.aspx.

Once downloaded, upload the `Sitecore.IdentityServer.scwdp.zip` to the same location as your other web deploy packages and reference it in your `parameters.json`.